# what's this indentationError?

Tags: python

```
print("Welcome to calculator.py")
print ("your options are :")
print ("")
print ("1) Addition")
print ("2)Subtraction")
print ("3) Multiplication")
print ("4)Division")
print ("Choose your option")


#this adds 2 numbers given

def add (a,b):
print(a, "+" ,b, "=" ,a+b)

#this subtracts 2 numbers given
def sub (a,b):
print(a, "-" ,b, "=" ,b-a)

#this multiplies 2 numbers given
def mul(a,b):
print(a, "*" ,b, "=" ,a*b)

#this divides 2 numbers given
def div(a,b):
def div(a, "/" ,b, "=" ,a/b)

#NOW THE PROGRAM REALLY STARTS ,AS CODE IS RUN
loop = 1
choice = 0
while loop == 1:
choice = menu()

if choice == 1:
    add (input("Add this: "),input ("to this: "))

        elif choice == 2:
    sub(input("Subtract this: "),input ("from this: "))


    elif choice == 3:
    mul (input("Multiply this: "),input ("by this: "))

    elif choice == 4:
    div(input("Divide this: "),input ("by this: "))

    elif choice ==5:
        loop = 0

        print ("Thank you for using calculator.py")
```

this is my code and the error is:
    print(a, "+" ,b, "=" ,a+b)
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block

Process finished with exit code 1
and many others can anyone help me find all the errors???
can anyone help me???

Comment: You need to indent after `def():` and in other places (basically always after a colon `:`) and you need to de-indent too in a few places

Answer (score 1):

In python, there are identation rules to know how the program should execute commands. This is the way python recognize when a function, a conditional statement or for, while statements start and end. In your case, for example, the elif statement should be at the same "level" as your initial if statement start:

```
print("Welcome to calculator.py")
print ("your options are :")
print ("")
print ("1) Addition")
print ("2)Subtraction")
print ("3) Multiplication")
print ("4)Division")
print ("Choose your option")


#this adds 2 numbers given

def add (a,b):
    print(a, "+" ,b, "=" ,a+b)

#this subtracts 2 numbers given
def sub (a,b):
    print(a, "-" ,b, "=" ,b-a)

#this multiplies 2 numbers given
def mul(a,b):
    print(a, "*" ,b, "=" ,a*b)

#this divides 2 numbers given
def div(a,b):
def div(a, "/" ,b, "=" ,a/b)

#NOW THE PROGRAM REALLY STARTS ,AS CODE IS RUN
loop = 1
choice = 0
while loop == 1:
    choice = menu()

if choice == 1:
    add (input("Add this: "),input ("to this: "))

elif choice == 2:
    sub(input("Subtract this: "),input ("from this: "))


elif choice == 3:
    mul (input("Multiply this: "),input ("by this: "))

elif choice == 4:
    div(input("Divide this: "),input ("by this: "))

elif choice ==5:
    loop = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

In python blocks are defined by indentation. After defining function you should have a indentation(tab).

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much all of the indentation is wrong, not just that one place:

```
print("Welcome to calculator.py")
print("your options are :")
print("")
print("1) Addition")
print("2)Subtraction")
print("3) Multiplication")
print("4)Division")
print("Choose your option")


#this adds 2 numbers given

def add(a,b):
    print(a, "+", b, "=" , a+b)

#this subtracts 2 numbers given
def sub(a,b):
    print(a, "-", b, "=" , b-a)

#this multiplies 2 numbers given
def mul(a,b):
    print(a, "*", b, "=" , a*b)

#this divides 2 numbers given
def div(a,b):
    print(a, "/", b, "=", a/b)

#NOW THE PROGRAM REALLY STARTS, AS CODE IS RUN
loop = 1
choice = 0
while loop == 1:
    choice = menu()

    if choice == 1:
        add(input("Add this: "), input("to this: "))
    elif choice == 2:
        sub(input("Subtract this: "), input("from this: "))
    elif choice == 3:
        mul(input("Multiply this: "), input("by this: "))
    elif choice == 4:
        div(input("Divide this: "), input("by this: "))
    elif choice ==5:
        loop = 0

print ("Thank you for using calculator.py")
```